# Yes or no about room-temperature superconductivity?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity

On 14 October 2020, [Snider et al.](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-020-2801-z) reported the room-temperature superconductivity in Nature. And on 20 October, Hirsch and Marsiglio claimed its absence in [arXiv:2010.10307](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.10307). What is the conclusion?

Comment: As with all science questions, time and more experiments are needed when there is a complicated controversy. Obviously the latter authors were not part of the peer review team for the acceptance of the publication :) , but I have not found by searching supporters of their view..

Comment: @anna-v Thank you for your comment/answer. I'm an amateur so I cannot judge properly, but it seems the pre-print's validity is decreasing with time.

Comment: [Talantsev (arXiv:2010.10434)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.10434) argues that the situation is inconclusive. Probably we'll have to wait for independent experiments to know the conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

see also  arXiv:2012.10771, "Anomalous behavior in high-pressure carbonaceous sulfur hydride" by Dogan and Cohen